# Python BeautifulSoup Loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Thanks to this board I have managed to retrieve the name and the price of the item I want using this code:

```
import urllib2  
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.toolventure.co.uk/hand-tools/saws/').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
item = re.sub('\s+', ' ', soup.h2.a.text)
price = soup.find('p', '*price').text
price = re.search('\d+\.\d+', price).group(0)

print item, price
```

This is great as it returns one result perfectly. Moving on I am now trying to retrieve ALL the results on the page. I have been playing around with loops but am very new to this and am unable to work out how to loop it.

Can someone more knowledgeable point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: all of which items are you looking for? h2.a? regardless `findAll` will help. This will return a list of matching elements.

Comment: For example, the above code spits out: Spear & Jackson Predator Universal Hardpoint Saw - 22" 5.95 which is perfect. Adding findAll to the current item = re.sub('\s+', ' ', soup.h2.a.text) creates an error. If i do

desc = soup.findAll('h2')
for desc in desc:
    print desc.text

then it returns all the items

Comment: Rubi STAR50-N PLUS Tile Cutter in Kit Box
Rubi STAR50-N Tile Cutter in Kit Box etc etc

However I am unable to get the price element in the loop as it throws an error on the reg expression (expects string error). So now I need to figure out how to return all the prices at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `findAll` for this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

mostwant = {'class': 'productlist_mostwanted_item '}
griditem = {'class': 'productlist_grid_item '}

divs = soup.findAll(attrs = mostwant) + soup.findAll(attrs = griditem)

for product in divs:
    item = product.h2.a.text.strip()
    price = re.search('\d+\.\d+', product.findAll('p')[1].text).group(0)
    print(f"{item} - {price}")
```

Comment: Epic! Thanks ever so much! That gives me something to learn as well. Top work.