# BeautifulSoup how to use for loops and extract specific data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The HTML code below is from a website regarding movie reviews. I want to extract the Stars from the code below, which would be `John C. Reilly`, `Sarah Silverman` and `Gal Gadot`. How could I do this?

Code:

```
html_doc = """
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="credit_summary_item">
                <h4 class="inline">Stars:</h4>
            <a href="/name/nm0000604/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm">John C. Reilly</a>,
            <a href="/name/nm0798971/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm">Sarah Silverman</a>,
            <a href="/name/nm2933757/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm">Gal Gadot</a>
            <span class="ghost">|</span>
            <a href="fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm">See full cast & crew</a>&nbsp;&raquo;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

### My idea

I was going to use for loops to iterate through each `div class` until I found the class with text `Stars`, in which I could then extract the names. But I don't how I would code this as I am not too familiar with HTML syntax nor the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python BeautifulSoup Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680905/python-beautifulsoup-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all `a` tags in the `credit_summary_item` `div`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
*results, _ = [i.text for i in soup(html_doc, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'credit_summary_item'}).find_all('a')]
```

Output:

```
['John C. Reilly', 'Sarah Silverman', 'Gal Gadot']
```

Edit:

```
_d = [i for i in soup(html_doc, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'credit_summary_item'}) if 'Stars:' in i.text][0]
*results, _ = [i.text for i in _d.find_all('a')]
```

Output:

```
['John C. Reilly', 'Sarah Silverman', 'Gal Gadot']
```

Comment: There is more than one `div` with class `credit_summary_item`.

Comment: @Newbie101 Does the `div` with the actors' names always appear first in the HTML? If so, then this solution will still work.

Comment: I got message `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'`?

Comment: @Newbie101 What line is throwing that error? This code works fine for me. `ResultSet` errors are generally raised when attempting to call methods directly on the results of a `find_all`, rather than iterating over it.

Comment: The error is gone. When I do `print(results)`, it prints `Rich Moore`? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @Newbie101 In my edited section, I added a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

I will show how to implement this, and see that you only need to learn BeautifulSoap syntax.

First, we want to use that method `findAll` for the "div" tag with the attribute "class".

```
divs = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "credit_summary_item"})
```

Then, we will filter all the divs without stars in it:

```
stars = [div for div in divs if "Stars:" in div.h4.text]
```

If you have only one place with start you can take it out:

```
star = start[0]
```

Then again find all the text in tag "a"

```
names = [a.text for a in star.findAll("a")]
```

You can see that I didn't used any html/css syntax, only soup.
I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

```
stars = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/name/nm.+'))
names = [x.text for x in stars]
names

# output: ['John C. Reilly', 'Sarah Silverman', 'Gal Gadot']
```